# Error in SQL Server Job [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 14636)

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I have a problem with one of my jobs in SQL Server. This job executes two steps, one per stored procedure.

The stored procedure works fine when it is executed, but in the job, it throws an error

> [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 14636)

Can you help me?

Comment: *"Can you help me?"* not with the *significant* lack of information we have. No. You need to give way more details here.

Comment: A look at [Database Engine Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15) says that the error number means *"No global profile is configured. Specify a profile name in the @profile_name parameter."*; that's already more information that we have in your question and seems to be explicitly telling you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you don't have a default profile set for database mail.

```
SELECT profile_id, name FROM msdb..sysmail_profile
```

then

```
UPDATE msdb..sysmail_principalprofile
SET is_default = 1
WHERE profile_id = <yourprofileid>
```